# Ruby on Rails Paperclip - Files not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, paperclip, attachment

I have it setup so that my user model has the attached file `:photo`:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
              :url  => "../avatars/:basename.:extension",
              :path => ":rails_root/public/avatars/:basename.:extension"
validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

To try and make use of this, I've added a field for avatar uploads in the user `edit` view:

```
<% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
#Unimportant Stuff here
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
#Unimportant Stuff here
<% end %>
```

And then created the `edit` and `update` methods in my user controller:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
     else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
end
```

My issue is that with all of this, uploading files still doesn't work. On visiting a users' page and uploading an image, I just get "Missing" where the image is supposed to be. If I set the image to a required field, I get an error stating that the filename is required (so I guess the uploading just isn't working correctly?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the columns paperclip expects to see to your table?

Comment: Also make sure in your dev log that that the images are actually being saved into your model.  Your model needs four specific columns for each paperclip attachment and you must rake db:migrate before hand.

Comment: I ran "script/generate paperclip user photo" and migrated the database so this cant be the cause of the problem. Also, no - my attachments are not appearing in my public directory after I upload them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create the folder structure where the attachments are supposed to be saved into.

Comment: Paperclip creates the structure for you (however just incase I just tried creating the "avatars" folder in public and it made no difference).

Comment: Strange. I am pretty sure that I had the same problem as you and that it was solved by creating the folder structure... Maybe you have a typo, or maybe you are not setting the pathes correctly...

Comment: Is your application ran with enough privileges to write files there?